Não consigo mudar a cor dos ítens da minha lista de tarefas, quando clico no checkbox, usando JS
Estou tentando fazer uma lista de tarefas, onde algumas tags são criadas dentro do Javascript. Eu consegui adicionar as tarefas na lista, porém gostaria que ao clicar no checkbox, ela mudasse de cor. Acontece que do jeito que fiz apenas a última tarefa muda de cor. Já tentei várias formas de fazer, não tenho mais os códigos pra mostrar, pois fui fazendo e quando não dava certo, deletava. Gostaria de saber se tem como a mudança de cor aconteça e por que não está funcionando.


let addDiv = document.getElementById('addDiv');
let novoInput = document.createElement('input');
novoInput.id = 'campo';
novoInput.className = 'campo';
novoInput.type = 'text';
novoInput.placeholder = 'Adicione sua tarefa';

let botao = document.createElement('button');
botao.type = "submit";
botao.id = 'botao';
botao.className = 'botao';
botao.textContent = 'ADICIONAR';
addDiv.append(novoInput, botao);

let valor = 0;
let li;
let lis = [];
let checkbox;
let checkboxs = [];

function addTarefa() {
  checkbox = document.createElement('input');
  checkbox.type = 'checkbox';
  checkbox.name = 'check';
  checkbox.id = 'check'
  checkbox.className = 'check'
  li = document.createElement('li');
  li.className = 'item';
  li.id = 'item'
  valor = document.getElementById('campo').value;
  li.append(checkbox, document.createTextNode(valor));
  document.getElementById("tarefas").appendChild(li);
  lis.push(li)
  checkbox.addEventListener('change', () => {

    for (let i = 0; i < lis.length; i++) {

      if (checkbox.checked) {
        li.style.color = 'rgba(255, 153, 51, 1)';
      } else {
        li.style.color = 'rgba(2, 110, 128, 1)';
      }
    }

  })
}
botao.addEventListener('click', addTarefa);
<pre>
    <div id="titulo" class="divTitulo">
      <h3 class="titulo">Lista de Tarefas</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
        <div id="addDiv" class="addDiv" style="text-align: center;"></div>
    <div>
        <ul  id="tarefas" class="tarefas"></ul>
    </div>
    </div>
    </pre>




Acontece que do jeito que fiz apenas a última tarefa muda de cor.
Exatamente. Veja que no seu código, a variável checkbox é usada assim:
let checkbox;
....
checkbox = document.createElement('input');
...
if(checkbox.checked){

Usei só a parte relevante para explicar.
Na primeira linha é criada a variável, então há uma referência para ela em todo o código;
Na segunda linha é atribuido a essa variável a referência ao elemento "checkbox" que foi criado;
Na terceira, já dentro da function que é disparada no click, é usada novamente a variável, que faz referência ao último elemento que foi criado. Note que, na segunda vez que criar um elemento, a referência passa a ser a esse elemento, e assim por diante, fazendo com que toda vez que a function ler essa variável, vai ter o valor do último elemento que foi criado!
É importante que a função possa trabalhar com a refência correta do elemento à qual ela deve tratar. Isso pode ser feito passando por parâmetro o elemento. Os event listeners passam isso implicitamente por parâmetro para as funções, e basta "pegar essa referência". Para ser mais claro, vamos chamar essa referência do evento que foi disparado e que acionou a function de event, e vamos passá-lo corretamente como parâmetro assim:
checkbox.addEventListener('change', (event)=>{
Essa variável event tem toda a informação do evento, no seu caso o "click", e ele tem uma propriedade chamada target, que contém o elemento que disparou o evento, no caso, o "checkbox".  Assim com event.target já temos o checkbox correto, mas ainda nos falta chegar ao elemento "LI" que você deseja mudar o estilo.
Como o "checkbox" foi adicionado ao elemento "LI", esse último é o parentElement do "checkbox", que pode ser acessado pela propriedade parentElement. Assim, para corrigir as referências, podemos adicionar as seguintes linhas de código dentro da function:
 const checkbox = event.target;
 const li = checkbox.parentElement;

Isso vai criar duas variáveis, dentro do escopo da function com as referências corretas aos elementos que precisamos tratar.
O comando for na funcion é desnecessário, uma vez que já sabamos exatamente que elementos devemos tratar, então o código da function fica simplemente assim:
checkbox.addEventListener('change', (event)=>{
    const checkbox = event.target;
    const li = checkbox.parentElement;

    if(checkbox.checked){
        li.style.color = 'rgba(255, 153, 51, 1)';
    }
    else{
        li.style.color = 'rgba(2, 110, 128, 1)';
    }
})

Note que, estou apenas explicando o problema da referência da variável e da passagem de parâmetros que é a dúvida principal, mas muitas melhorias precisam ser feitas nesse código, e sugiro estudar algumas como:

remover as variávies que não são utilizadas;
substituir o style in-line da função por uma classe css (estudar o classList, tem exemplos de código no link);
identar corretamente o código;

Veja aqui funcionando:


let addDiv = document.getElementById('addDiv');
let novoInput = document.createElement('input');
novoInput.id = 'campo';
novoInput.className = 'campo';
novoInput.type = 'text';
novoInput.placeholder = 'Adicione sua tarefa';

let botao = document.createElement('button');
botao.type = "submit";
botao.id = 'botao';
botao.className = 'botao';
botao.textContent = 'ADICIONAR';
addDiv.append(novoInput, botao);

let valor = 0;
let lis = [];
let checkboxs = [];

    function addTarefa(){
        const checkbox = document.createElement('input');
        checkbox.type = 'checkbox';
        checkbox.name = 'check';
        checkbox.id = 'check'
        checkbox.className = 'check'
        
        const li = document.createElement('li');
        li.className = 'item';
        li.id = 'item'
        valor = document.getElementById('campo').value;
        li.append(checkbox, document.createTextNode(valor));
        document.getElementById("tarefas").appendChild(li);
        lis.push(li)
        checkbox.addEventListener('change', (event)=>{
            const checkbox = event.target;
            const li = checkbox.parentElement; 

            if(checkbox.checked){
                li.style.color = 'rgba(255, 153, 51, 1)';
            }
            else{
                li.style.color = 'rgba(2, 110, 128, 1)';
            }
        })
    }
    botao.addEventListener('click', addTarefa);
<pre>
  <div id="titulo" class="divTitulo">
    <h3 class="titulo">Lista de Tarefas</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
      <div id="addDiv" class="addDiv" style="text-align: center;"></div>
      <div>
        <ul  id="tarefas" class="tarefas"></ul>
      </div>
  </div>
</pre>




Por que os negativos? Para mim funcionou e a explicação está um pouco prolixa mas faz sentido.

Acho que entendi o porque dos negativos. Eu pensei um pouco e esse problema pode ser resolvido de forma simples com CSS sem javascript.

se simplesmente fizer isso, vai ter que explicar o conceito de seletores, enquanto a pergunta se foca em javascript... além disso, não ia explicar o problema em si, que poderia ser útil a outras pessoas... de qq forma, negativos aqui são o padrão, já estou acostumado @AugustoVasques
